# Read excel file in each line for each record in array structure

Tags: java, excel

I am trying to read excel file from java in array
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.IOException;

```
import jxl.Cell;
import jxl.Sheet;
import jxl.Workbook;
import jxl.read.biff.BiffException;
public class ArrayData
{

private String inputFile;
String[][] data = null;
public void setInputFile(String inputFile) 
{
    this.inputFile = inputFile;
}

public String[][] read() throws IOException  
{
    File inputWorkbook = new File(inputFile);
    Workbook w;

    try 
    {
        w = Workbook.getWorkbook(inputWorkbook);
        // Get the first sheet


        Sheet sheet = w.getSheet(0);
        data = new String[sheet.getColumns()][sheet.getRows()];
        // Loop over first 10 column and lines
      System.out.println(sheet.getColumns() +  " " +sheet.getRows());
        for (int j = 0; j <sheet.getColumns(); j++) 
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < sheet.getRows(); i++) 
            {
                Cell cell = sheet.getCell(j, i);
                data[j][i] = cell.getContents();
              //  System.out.println(cell.getContents());
            }
        }

        for (int j = 0; j < data.length; j++) 
        {
            for (int i = 0; i <data[j].length; i++) 
            {

                System.out.println(data[j][i]);
            }
        } 

    } 
    catch (BiffException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
return data;
}
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException 
{
    ArrayData test = new ArrayData();
    test.setInputFile("StockTickerStreamData.xls");
    test.read();
}
}
```

When i run it, the result shows everything in 1 column. how can i make it show in each line so that everything looks like the one in excel?
[Here is my Data in excel file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m66uh.png)

Answer (score 0):

Your output loop is:

```
    for (int j = 0; j < data.length; j++) {
        for (int i = 0; i <data[j].length; i++) {
            System.out.println(data[j][i]);
        }
    }
```

As println terminates each output with a new line, you'll end up with a cell each row.

You need to "print" the cells, and followup with a "println" for the newline at the end of each row. Something along the lines of:

```
    for (int j = 0; j < data.length; j++) {
        for (int i = 0; i <data[j].length; i++) {
            System.out.print(data[j][i] + ";");   // no "ln" ;-)
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

Comment: Isit possible to show the output by row and column? as the output now is showing by row
    Date;20140102;20140102;20140102;20140102;20140102;20140102;2

    Time;08:39.0;13:59.0;17:00.0;17:0

    Price;1.44;1.44;1.44;

Comment: Best, turn the indices in your data structure around while reading. Right now, you have data indexed as column/row - you might be better off with row/column. Otherwise, you'd have to know how far to loop beforehand, create an outer loop over rows and an inner loop over columns instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can display it in a better view just like below but cant probably display it like in row column manner.

**OUTPUT :**

[image]

**CODE :**

```
for (int j = 0; j < data.length; j++) {
            for (int i = 0; i <data[j].length; i++) {
                if(data[j][i].equals("BidPrice")|| data[j][i].equals("AskPrice")){
                    System.out.print(data[j][i] + "\t");
                }else{
                    System.out.print(data[j][i] + "\t\t");
                }
            }

            System.out.println();
        }
```

Comment: Is there any method that i could search the excel file? for example i want to search prices